# Angular + Karma + Gitlab CI: Karma tests timing out

Tags: angular, gitlab, continuous-integration, karma-runner

My karma test jobs aren't terminating properly on Gitlab CI.

The test job is called with `ng test --progress false --watch false`.

The tests run and return a successful result:

```
TOTAL: 16 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 16 SUCCESS
```

However the job never terminates with the gitlab `Job succeeded` message.

The pipeline was running perfectly yesterday and nothing has changed in the `gitlab-ci.yml` file.

What could be causing this and what can be done to address the problem?

Edit: This seems to be a result of the recent `trion/ng-cli-karma` update to version 14.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually an issue described in this ticket: https://github.com/trion-development/docker-ng-cli-karma/issues/14

Comment: It should be fixed in a later release.

Answer (score 1):

The new version `trion/ng-cli-karma (14.0.0)` doesn't seem to handle the `--watch` argument correctly in the Gitlab CI currently for some reason. Until then, a work-around for now can be to use version `(13.3.7)` which is the currently latest one working. Notable though is that it seems to work outside the Gitlab CI.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem and I post in here https://github.com/trion-development/docker-ng-cli-karma/issues/14#issuecomment-1648243510.